# Loading visible images

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, lazy

I am using this code to get images to load only if they are visible. However, it seems to be slow with thousands of images, even if they are not rendered.

```
function getViewportHeight() {
    if(window.innerHeight) {
        return window.innerHeight;
    }
    else if(document.body && document.body.offsetHeight) {
        return document.body.offsetHeight;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
function inView(elem, nearThreshold) {
    var viewportHeight = getViewportHeight();
    var scrollTop = (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop);
    var elemTop = elem.offset().top;
    var elemHeight = elem.height();
    nearThreshold = nearThreshold || 0;
    if((scrollTop + viewportHeight + nearThreshold) > (elemTop + elemHeight)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function loadVisibleImages() {
    jQuery('img[data-src]').each(function() {
        if(jQuery(this).is(':visible')) {
            if(inView(jQuery(this), 100)) {
                this.src = jQuery(this).attr('data-src');
            }
        }
    });
}

jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    loadVisibleImages();
});
```

I am using this code to render images:

```
<img src="" data-src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="" width="400" height="400">
```

Everything works, but how can I optimize it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few callouts/suggestions:

You should throttle your code on the `scroll` event.  That way the event doesn't fire thousands of times.  You can read up [this article](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) for more information.  A basic example would be:

```
//which makes the `scroll` event fire every 250ms.
$(window).scroll( $.throttle( 250, loadVisibleImages) );
```

You probably don't need to get the viewport size every time through the loop.  This should be called once at the start and then only on the `resize` event.  Otherwise, it never changes so there is no need to re-calculate it.

```
//which makes the `resize` event fire every 250ms.
$(window).resize( $.throttle( 250, getViewportHeight) );
```

You can add a class to all the images that have already been processed and exclude them from your selector.  This way you are only dealing with new images.
For example:

```
function loadVisibleImages() {
  jQuery('img[data-src]').not('.processed').each(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).is(':visible')) {
        if(inView(jQuery(this), 100)) {
            this.src = jQuery(this).attr('data-src').addClass('processed');
        }
    }
  });
}
```

If you haven't already you should wrap your code in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) so you can create a private scope.  Just take the code below and put it around your existing code.  This would also allow you to use `$` for `jQuery` without worry.

```
(function( $ ) {
  //your code here
}) ( jQuery );
```

You could optimize the loop in your `loadVisibleImages` functions.  See your [other question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90160/how-can-i-rewrite-this-code-to-a-native-js-for-loop).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Very valid points with the resize and the throttle functions. Let me test the code and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I had to rewrite the function, as jQuery `:visible` is quite slow, so I decided to implement the function for each AJAX call. But the answer is correct and it speeds up the function a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In method `inView` you recount variables which are the same for every scroll position:

```
viewportHeight, scrollTop,nearThreshold and their sum
```

You can count them once in the scroll event handler and then pass to `inView` only their sum.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a fan of nesting statements more than you have to, I would suggest that you un-nest this piece of code a little bit to make it a little bit cleaner(in my opinion)

> ```
> function loadVisibleImages() {
>     jQuery('img[data-src]').each(function() {
>         if(jQuery(this).is(':visible')) {
>             if(inView(jQuery(this), 100)) {
>                 this.src = jQuery(this).attr('data-src');
>             }
>         }
>     });
> }
> ```

like this

```
function loadVisibleImages() {
    jQuery('img[data-src]').each(function() {
        if(jQuery(this).is(':visible') && inView(jQuery(this), 100)) {
            this.src = jQuery(this).attr('data-src');
        }
    });
}
```

It is essentially the same thing that you have, except for that it is not nested as deeply.

---

also inside of your `inView` function you could eliminate the if statement at the end, it would change from this

> ```
> if((scrollTop + viewportHeight + nearThreshold) > (elemTop + elemHeight)) {
>     return true;
> }
> return false;
> ```

to this

```
return (scrollTop + viewportHeight + nearThreshold) > (elemTop + elemHeight)
```